# Python MySQL - SELECT in loop and INSERT with threading

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

I'm quite new to Python, so I don't know if what and how I want to do this is the best way, but this was the only idea...

So, I have something like this:

```
import MySQLdb
from threading import Thread

global conn

def led_on(zona):
    #do something here
    #this takes some time, so there will be simultaneous threads running
    c2 = conn.cursor()
    c2.execute("UPDATE zone SET status='0' WHERE id=%s", (str(zona),))
    conn.commit()
    c2.close()

def check_db(zona):
    c.execute("SELECT starting_time, duration FROM schedule WHERE id_zona=%s", (str(zona),))
    ore_incepere = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("SELECT status FROM zone WHERE id=%s", (str(zona),))
    info_zone = c.fetchone()
    for row in ore_incepere:
        if (some conditions here):
            c.execute("UPDATE zone SET status='1' WHERE id=%s", (str(zona),))
            t = Thread(target=led_on, args=(zona))
            t.start()
    c.close()

try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="pi", passwd="mypass", db="raspberry")
    while True:
        conn.begin() #I put this here (in the loop), because starting_time from schedule table can be modified outside this script, so I need to see those changes
        check_db(1)
except Exception as e: print(e)
```

So, why I did all this? I want that this script to run continuously, just like a service and if the starting_time from schedule table is the same with the current time, then change the status in the zone table to 1 and run the led_on() function, in a thread. At the end of the led_on() function, the status should be updated back to 0.

All this, sometimes work, sometimes not and returns the following error:

> Exception in thread Thread-4: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)   File "/home/pi/Documents/Adi/db/db_mysql.py", line 26, in led_on
>       c3.close()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 75, in
>   close
>       while self.nextset(): pass   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 107, in
>   nextset
>       nr = db.next_result() ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

Any help with this? Many thanks!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html